# Get All Spiders Class name in Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

in the older version we could get the list of spiders(spider names ) with following code, but  in the current version (1.4) I faced with

```
[py.warnings] WARNING: run-all-spiders.py:17: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: CrawlerRunner.spiders attribute is renamed to CrawlerRunner.spider_loader.
for spider_name in process.spiders.list():
    # list all the available spiders in my project
```

Use `crawler.spiders.list()`:

```
>>> for spider_name in crawler.spiders.list():
...     print(spider_name)
```

How Can I get spiders list (and equivalent class names) in Scrapy?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm using this in my utility script for running spiders:

```
from scrapy import spiderloader
from scrapy.utils import project

settings = project.get_project_settings()
spider_loader = spiderloader.SpiderLoader.from_settings(settings)
spiders = spider_loader.list()
classes = [spider_loader.load(name) for name in spiders]
```

In you case, it should suffice to rename `spiders` to `spider_loader` as suggested by the warning message.